# Whiptail Gauge: Variable in loop not being set

Tags: linux, bash, whiptail

Am new to bash and whiptail so excuse the ignorance.

When assigning a var in the for loop, the new value of 20 is never set when using a Whiptail dialog.  Any suggestions why ?

```
andy="10"
{
    for ((i = 0 ; i <= 100 ; i+=50)); do
        andy="20"
        echo $i
        sleep 1
    done
 } | whiptail --gauge "Please wait" 5 50 0 
# }
echo "My val $andy
```

Comment: @shellter `()` is a subshell. `{}` is not. The problem is the pipe.

Answer (score 4):

A command inside a pipeline (that is, a series of commands separated by `|`) is always executed in a subshell, which means that each command has its own variable environment. The same is true of the commands inside the compound command `(…)`, but not the compound command `{…}`, which can normally be used for grouping without creating a subshell.

In `bash` or `zsh`, you can solve this problem using process substitution instead of a pipeline. For example:

```
andy="10"
for ((i=0 ; i <= 100 ; i+=50)); do
        andy="20"
        echo $i
        sleep 1
done > >(whiptail --gauge "Please wait" 6 50 0) 
echo "My val $andy
```

`>(whiptail ...)` will cause a subshell to be created to execute `whiptail`; the entire expression will be substituted by the name of this subshell's standard input (in linux, it will be something like `/dev/fd/63`, but it could be a FIFO on other OSs). `> >(...)` causes standard output to be redirected to the subshell's standard input; the first `>` is just a normal stdout redirect.

Comment: Many thanks - substitution instead of a pipeline did the trick

Comment: @user3761314 I don't know if you've ever made your way back to StackOverflow... but if you come back, it would be nice to mark this answer as "accepted" (click the gray ✔ in the left margin of the answer near the votes).

Comment: @rici 8 years later, this answer helped me sort and solve days' worth of debugging  I'd realized I was using `()` subshells in one area of my script, and happily rectified that... only to find out that piping to `dialog` for the gauge was munging my variables!

Answer (score 1):

The statements inside `{}` are not ordinarily executed in a sub-shell. However, when you add a pipe (`|`) to it, they seem to be executed in a sub-shell.

If you remove the pipe to `whiptail`, you will see the update value of `andy`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I used substitution in place of the pipe, which worked.